# PHP - Incrementally add array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I have this from a query:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [period] => 2014-03
        [val] => 2.19
        [type] => TypeX
    ),
[1] => Array
    (
        [period] => 2014-03
        [val] => 2.02
        [type] => TypeY
    )
)
```

Using a foreach loop to populate another array we will call DATA, I want the to get the following:

```
Array
(
[TypeX] => Array
    (
        [2014-03] => 2.19
    )
[TypeY] => Array
    (
        [2014-03] => 2.02
    )
 )
```

The whole thing is looped because my query needs to run each time for a different period. Current exemple, second loop would run for 2014-04. My problem is when I arrive for the 2nd time at my DATA array, I want this:

```
Array
(
[TypeX] => Array
    (
        [2014-03] => 2.19
        [2014-04] => 1.10

    )
[TypeY] => Array
    (
        [2014-03] => 2.02
        [2014-04] => 4.74
    )
)
```

My code is roughly like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach($graph_period as $period){
$rows = Queryfunction($period,$WHERE,$byType);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $data[$row['type']] = array($row['period']=>$row['val']);
        }
}
```

Because the key of the first level (TypeX, TypeY) are the same, the valei is overwritten. How am I to append the array instead of overwriting ?

Comment: You can probably get the SQL server to do all this for you without having to resort to juggling all the data in PHP.  Look up aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $data[$row['type']][$row['period']] = $row['val']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change a tiny bit. Inside the foreach where you set the value:

```
if( !isset($date[$row['type']]) ) {
  $data[$row['type']] = array();
}

$data[$row['type']][$row['period']] = $row['val'];
```

So, you create the array only if it does not exist.